# Get Category with a custom attribute programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, model

How can I load a category with only the value of a custom attribute in a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;

    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
     .....
     $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
     .....
    }

   $categories =   $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute',$custom_value)->load();
```

Comment: Try to avoid load() when getting collection().

Comment: Then what to use ?

Comment: You are using ResourceModel means there  have already getcollection().
$this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute',$custom_value);